How can you convert a kafka message into a different json format
I have this debezium message that was created at source and dropped into a topic
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
            {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_001"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_002"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_003"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_004"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_005"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_006"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_007"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_008"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_009"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_010"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_011"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_012"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_013"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_014"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_015"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_016"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_017"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_018"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "_sling_loaded_at"
                    }
                ],
                "optional": true,
                "name": "tpcds.public.customer.Value",
                "field": "before"
            },
            {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_001"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_002"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_003"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_004"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_005"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_006"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_007"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_008"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_009"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_010"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_011"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_012"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_013"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_014"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_015"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_016"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_017"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "col_018"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "_sling_loaded_at"
                    }
                ],
                "optional": true,
                "name": "tpcds.public.customer.Value",
                "field": "after"
            },
            {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "version"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "connector"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "name"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "ts_ms"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "name": "io.debezium.data.Enum",
                        "version": 1,
                        "parameters": {
                            "allowed": "true,last,false,incremental"
                        },
                        "default": "false",
                        "field": "snapshot"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "db"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "sequence"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "schema"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "table"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "txId"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "lsn"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "xmin"
                    }
                ],
                "optional": false,
                "name": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source",
                "field": "source"
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": false,
                "field": "op"
            },
            {
                "type": "int64",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "ts_ms"
            },
            {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "id"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "total_order"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "data_collection_order"
                    }
                ],
                "optional": true,
                "name": "event.block",
                "version": 1,
                "field": "transaction"
            }
        ],
        "optional": false,
        "name": "tpcds.public.customer.Envelope",
        "version": 1
    },
    "payload": {
        "before": {
            "col_001": 6,
            "col_002": "AAAAAAAAGAAAAAAA",
            "col_003": 213219,
            "col_004": 6374,
            "col_005": 27082,
            "col_006": 2451883,
            "col_007": 2451853,
            "col_008": "Ms.",
            "col_009": "Brunilda aaa bbb ccc ddd",
            "col_010": "Sharp",
            "col_011": "Y",
            "col_012": 4,
            "col_013": 12,
            "col_014": 1925,
            "col_015": "SURINAME",
            "col_016": null,
            "col_017": "Brunilda.Sharp@T3pylZEUQjm.org",
            "col_018": 2452430,
            "_sling_loaded_at": 1713464143
        },
        "after": {
            "col_001": 6,
            "col_002": "AAAAAAAAGAAAAAAA",
            "col_003": 213219,
            "col_004": 6374,
            "col_005": 27082,
            "col_006": 2451883,
            "col_007": 2451853,
            "col_008": "Ms.",
            "col_009": "Brunilda aaa bbb ccc ddd eee",
            "col_010": "Sharp",
            "col_011": "Y",
            "col_012": 4,
            "col_013": 12,
            "col_014": 1925,
            "col_015": "SURINAME",
            "col_016": null,
            "col_017": "Brunilda.Sharp@T3pylZEUQjm.org",
            "col_018": 2452430,
            "_sling_loaded_at": 1713464143
        },
        "source": {
            "version": "2.5.4.Final",
            "connector": "postgresql",
            "name": "tpcds",
            "ts_ms": 1713471958528,
            "snapshot": "false",
            "db": "tpcds",
            "sequence": "[\"108523976\",\"108524328\"]",
            "schema": "public",
            "table": "customer",
            "txId": 777,
            "lsn": 108524328,
            "xmin": null
        },
        "op": "u",
        "ts_ms": 1713471958951,
        "transaction": null
    }
}

I have sink connector and it needs it in this format
{
            "col_001": 1,
            "col_002": "AAAAAAAAGAAAAAAA",
            "col_003": 213219,
            "col_004": 6374,
            "col_005": 27082,
            "col_006": 2451883,
            "col_007": 2451853,
            "col_008": "Ms.",
            "col_009": "Brunilda aaa",
            "col_010": "Sharp",
            "col_011": "Y",
            "col_012": 4,
            "col_013": 12,
            "col_014": 1925,
            "col_015": "SURINAME",
            "col_016": null,
            "col_017": "Brunilda.Sharp@T3pylZEUQjm.org",
            "col_018": 2452430,
            "_sling_loaded_at": 1713464143,
            "__op": 1
}

I image I need to use kafka sink transforms but I'm not sure how to do it.  Any ideas?


https://debezium.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/302529-community-general/topic/Convert.20a.20debezium.20message.20to.20a.20custom.20built.20kafka.20sink.3F/near/435523640

Use event flattening / New Record State Extraction.
You've not provided your Kafka Connect config so I can't illustrate directly how to use it, but the Debezium docs are very good and clear on this. You basically add a transforms entry for it.
